# Swift NSMutableArray add one more array

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, addition

The Problem is First time I get data from `WebServices` so I have show this data on `TableView` Then user scroller down tableview then again call `WebSevices` and add this data to again in array 
but when I try to add data again in nsmutable type array app is **crashing**

Here is my code. Any solution?

1st time Data load is Working

```
 var ary_mutable: NSMutableArray! 
 ary_mutable = NSMutableArray()
        ary_mutable=jsonResult as AnyObject as! NSMutableArray
                        self.tbl_T.reloadData();
                        self.tbl_T.delegate=self;
                        self.tbl_T.dataSource=self;
```

2nd Time data load and add with old array not Working

```
var myArray :NSArray!
                myArray = jsonResult as AnyObject as! NSArray
 ary_mutable.addObject(myArray.objectAtIndex(0))
```

Got This Error

```
[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

I have Try this code also But Not Working

```
ary_mutable.addObject(myArray)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create a mutable array from immutable. This:

```
ary_mutable=jsonResult as AnyObject as! NSMutableArray
```

does not do it, it is just a static cast from one type to another. You have to construct a new NSMutableArray and then fill it with required values.

Change your code to

```
var ary_mutable = NSMutableArray()

// everytime you receive a new data
ary_mutable.addObjectsFromArray(jsonResult as! [AnyObject])
```

Comment: This Code Replace old Data . But Requirement is (Old Array Data) + (New Array Data) Means First time load data now Count is 15 then again load 5 more data now array count is 20 Like this type please help me

Comment: Big Big Thankyouuuuuuuuuu its Working

Answer (score 2):

replace this code:

```
var myArray :NSArray!
myArray = jsonResult as AnyObject as! NSArray
ary_mutable.addObject(myArray.objectAtIndex(0))
```

with this code:

```
var myArray : NSMutableArray!
myArray = jsonResult as AnyObject as! NSMutableArray
ary_mutable.addObjectsFromArray(myArray as [AnyObject]);
```